# Android Management API and Android TV

Tags: android, api, television

in the guide for Android Management API it is said

```
Fully managed mode
In fully managed mode the entire device is managed and 
the device needs to be factory reset before setup. 
To set up a device in fully managed mode you need to use a QR code.

For devices running Android 7.0 or above:

Turn on a new or factory-reset device.
Tap the same spot on the welcome screen six times to enter QR code mode.
Connect to a WiFi network.
Scan the QR code.
```

My question is how to add TV that does not have touch support. Are TVs possible at all?

Comment: Hi, have you found an answer to this?

Comment: No, I gave up..

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if TVs are supported.

You can get more information at the below link :
https://www.android.com/intl/en_in/enterprise/devices/

You can also try **DPC identifier method**

If Android Device Policy can't be added via QR code or NFC a user or IT admin can follow these steps to provision a company-owned device:

1. Follow the setup wizard on a new or factory-reset device.
2. Enter Wi-Fi login details to connect the device to the internet.
3. When prompted to sign in, enter afw#setup, which downloads Android Device Policy.
4. Scan a QR code or manually enter an enrollment token to provision
   the device.

Answer (score 0):

No. Android Management API won't work on TV

Comment: Is there a way to make it work?